# product not able to add in required layout

Tags: html, magento-1.4

i want to add product in our layout please tell me how to do than i add product in my own layout please i hope u u must give me right answer for this question i have code but u tell me step by step process how to add

```
<li>
                        <div class="prd-main">
                        <div class="relative">
                        <div class="off-div position-off"> 10% Off </div>
                        </div>
                            <img src="images/prd-small1.gif" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="prd-text">Amoy Bean Strip</div>
                        <div class="prd-detail">
                            <div class="prd-detail-left">
                                Size : 250g<br />Sau Tao<br />
                                £0.95
                            </div>
                            <div class="prd-detail-right">
                                Qty <input name="" type="text" value="1" class="qut" />
                                <input name="" type="button" value="ADD TO BASKET" class="btn-addtocart" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

please give me answer this question i want to add this layout product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are new to HTML.  Here's a good guide on adding list items to your HTML page. http://www.goodellgroup.com/tutorial/chapter6.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably via

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

But this depends on the blocktype you have set for the template file in question.

Comment: this stance add in our template file